# How to create step forms in ionic 4 and angular 8?

Tags: ionic4, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

I have created five pages to hold five different forms. How can I create **save and next** type of feature for each forms until final one?

I'm using **reactive form module** for each forms.

Following is the file structure in case if question isn't clear.

```
app
 |-- form(folder)
 |----- step 1(folder)
 |---------step1-routing.module.ts
 |---------step1.module.ts
 |---------step1.page.html
 |---------step1.page.scss
 |---------step1.page.ts
 |----- step 2(folder)
 |----- step 3(folder)
 |----- step 4(folder)
 |----- step 5(folder)
```

Any suggestion and hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Can this be helpful for you [Ionic stepper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-stepper) ?

Comment: I have to go through the documentation and will let you know, definitely something good to check this out! - Thanks.

Comment: I'm wondering if I can call **another pages** from same view or not, or I have to create all form in single page and use **<ion-step>** tag

Comment: I feel that would be better to do so rather than storing and forwarding every form details on different pages.

Comment: The only reason I created separate page for all forms because each forms are lengthy and also each of them have dynamic generated fields too.

Comment: That's your choice how you wanna work on it.

Comment: Yes and Thankyou!!